# Scala diamond prob, find class name from instance of class D

Tags: scala, diamond-problem

I have four traits A, B, C and D in the typical diamond problem hierarchy.
I have implemented a method calculate in trait A which checks the instance of callerObject, performs some calculation and returns trait A type object. calculate method is successfully able to check the instanceType of callerObject when callerObject belongs to trait B or C but doesn't work for object of trait D and I get the following class cast exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: packageName.B$$anon$1 cannot be cast to packageName.D
```

Can you please suggest way forward, how can I check the Type of the object from trait D in method of trait A.

PS: I am new to Scala.

Comment: def calculate(other: A) : A = {
       this match {
          case _: B =>  //Some Function call and return B type obj
          case _: C => //Some Function call and return C type obj
          case _: D => //Some function call and return D type obj
      }
  }

Comment: No, I can't read this. Add it to your original question, format properly, amd show where you get the error. Add the class definitions too. Take a look here for guidance:http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sure I will post clean code shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pattern matching the order of the `case` statements matters. Make sure that the most specific class is always matched at the top. For example if `B extends A` and `C extends B`, it means that objects of C will always match anything that looks for either B or A, etc.

Here is a toy example that can better explain the solution:

```
sealed trait A {
   def calculate(i: A) = i match {
      case _:D => "d" // Make sure the D is checked first!
      case _:B => "b"
      case _:C => "c"
      // If you want to match for A make sure it is added last
   }
}
trait B extends A
trait C extends A
trait D extends B with C
```

Here is an example in the REPL:

```
val b = new B{}
val c = new C{}
val d = new D{}

b.calculate(b)
res> "b"
b.calculate(c)
res> "c"
b.calculate(d)
res> "d"
```

Comment: Exactly changing the order as suggested above worked for me, thank you very much.